# Complex line bundles over a Riemann surface can be given a holomorphic line bundle structure

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, line-bundles

In p.20 of this lecture note (link: [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cautis/math428/notes-bundles.pdf](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecautis/math428/notes-bundles.pdf)), it is written that every complex line bundle over a Riemann surface can be given a holomorphic line bundle structure. How can we prove this? Is there a reference for a proof of this statement?

P.S. I am also curious that for a Riemann surface $C$ and an integer $n$, does there exist a complex line bundle $L\to C$ such that $c_1[L]=n$?

Comment: Your P.S. follows from the statement in the first paragraph: $C_1[L]$ is the Euler number; simple topological constructions give oriented $\mathbb R^2$ bundles over $C$ of any Euler number; every oriented $\mathbb R^2$ bundle has a Riemannian metric, using a partition of unity argument; and every Riemannian metric determines a complex structure on the line bundle in which multiplication by $i$ is rotation by $90^\circ$ in the counterclockwise direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know some (basic) facts about complex/holomorphic line bundles over complex manifolds. I'll try to be much clear as possible.

(1) The first Chern class is a topological invariant for complex line bundles in the sense that it gives a group homomorphism $c_1:H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. So we can think of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ as the group parametrizing complex line bundles.

(2) Holomorphic line bundles are parametrized by $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)$

(3) There exists a long exact sequence of cohomology group, which the relevant part (for our purpose) is the following \begin{equation*}\cdots\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)\overset{c_1}{\to}H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to\cdots
\end{equation*}

But $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong H^{0,2}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ and since we are on a Riemann surface there no exist $(0,2)$-forms and therefore $H^{0,2}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\cong 0$. In particular from this follows that $c_1$ is surjective and by (1),(2) above that any complex line bundle over a Riemann surface admits a holomorphic structure.

For your second question just note that $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, so you can take your favorite integer $n$ and find a complex line bundle $L$ such that $\int_Xc_1(L)=n$. For example if $n>0$ take $\tilde{L}$ to be a degree $1$ line bundle and define $L:=\tilde{L}\underbrace{\otimes\dots\otimes}_{n \ \text{times}}\tilde{L}$ (note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$ and $-1$ as additive group)